# Error ClassNotFoundException en Symfony 3 Router

Tags: symfony3, router

Alguien me puede explicar el siguiente error en Symfony 3.0:

He creado un `bundle` llamado blog, para lo cual he definido la ruta `/blog`:

```
blog_homepage:
    path:     /blog
    defaults: { _controller: BlogBundle:Default:index }
```

Cuando empiezo a trabajar con las entidades me genera el siguiente error:

> ClassNotFoundException in appDevUrlGenerator.php line 14: Attempted to
>   load class "UrlGenerator" from namespace
>   "BlogBundle\Entity\Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator". Did you
>   forget a "use" statement for
>   "Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator"?

Después de tanto probar y probar, el error se corrige si cambio la ruta por otra (cabe indicar que no existe otra ruta llamada /blog), por ejemplo algo así:

```
blog_homepage:
    path:     /blogp
    defaults: { _controller: BlogBundle:Default:index }
```

Es algo muy absurdo, alguien me puede indicar por qué, y como corregirlo.

Comment: Probaste limpiar la cache ??

Comment: Edita la pregunta y muestra el código de las clases que se mencionan en el error, para tener mayor información

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifica que no te hayas descargado algún `bundle` que tenga esa ruta implementada.

A veces los `bundles` por ejemplo `EasyAdminBundle`, traen rutas por defecto que utilizan para acceder a sus distintas funcionalidades.